# Difference between reduceByKey(_+_) and reduceByKey (_++_) in Scala

Tags: scala

What is the difference between reduceByKey(*+*) and reduceByKey (*++*). I know the internal working of reduceByKey(*+*). But how reduceByKey (*++*) works internally. I have google reduceByKey (*++*) but not found any resource everyone is talking about reduceByKey (*+*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduceByKey` on a collection of elements of type `T` expects a **binary operation of type `Fucntion2[T, T, U]`**, which means it expects a function from two arguments with type `T` to a value with type `U`.

- If `+` is defined for type `T` (e.g. if `T` is `Int`, `Double`...), then `_ + _` adheres to this expected type.
- If `++` is defined for type `T` (e.g. when `T` is `List`), then `_ ++ _` adheres to this type.
- If neither is correct (e.g. `T` is your own class not defining any of these operators) then neither would compile.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same operation, but the way values are reduced (i.e. merged) is different (`++` instead of `+`). For example, if values are lists then `++` will concatenate them